# How to access the response/redirect after stripe payment?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

Im trying to sell videos on my website, hosted using wordpress. I have set up a Stripe account and been using "WP Simple Pay Lite for Stripe" Plugin on my website.

The problem that i'm facing is when I get a payment on stripe I manually send my customers the video that they have purchased. I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how I can automate the process by sending my customers the product once payment has been paid.

For this "WP Simple Pay Lite for Stripe" Plugin there is a successful payment URL redirect feature. That I was using before. How ever I noticed that you can view the successful payment redirect from the Developer Tools.

`<input type="hidden" name="sc-redirect" value="https://wpsimplepay.com/demo-success-page/">`

Comment: you want to hide this success url??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Stanimir Stoyanov** said, you can use `sc_after_charge` but his code won't work because `sc_after_charge` returns `Charge` object, not JSON.

```
/**
 * Sends video url to customer when payment is successful
 * @param $response \Stripe\Charge
 */
function send_video_if_payment_successful( $response ) {
    if ( $response->paid ) {
        // Maybe check amount and or description to ensure it's same product
        $file = 'http://url_to/file_to_attach.mp4'; // Video url
        $subject = 'Find your video here - My store'; // Email subject
        $msg = '
        Thanks for buying...
        yada yada yada...
        Please find attached video.'; // Email message

        $attachments = array( $file ); // Add attachment

        $headers = 'From: My store <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n"; // Set yourself in From header

        wp_mail( $response->receipt_email, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachments ); // Send the mail
    }
}
add_action( 'sc_after_charge', 'send_video_if_payment_successful' );
```

Here we first check if payment was successful, if yes, we the email the file to the user :)

If you plan to sell multiple products... You can set appropriate description and send different files for different descriptions accessible by `$response->description`

Comment: This way we also don't expose the url to video on our site... ;)

Answer (score 4):

In [this topic](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-new-user-on-successful-checkout/) which is similar to yours the author suggests to use [sc_after_charge](https://github.com/moonstonemedia/WP-Simple-Pay-Library/blob/master/simple-pay/action-sc_after_charge.php) hook. So your code will be:

```
add_action( 'sc_after_charge', 'sc_after_charge_example' );
function sc_after_charge_example( $charge_response ) {
    if ( $charge_response->paid ) {
        $url = 'https://wpsimplepay.com/demo-success-page/';

        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am not sure abou the response type and if its JSON, but in [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge) it's a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In the short code add success_redirect_url="https://wpsimplepay.com/demo-success-page" as an attribute

```
[stripe name="My Store" description="My Product" amount="1999" success_redirect_url="https://wpsimplepay.com/demo-success-page"]
```

Source: https://wpsimplepay.com/docs/shortcodes/stripe-checkout/

Answer (score 1):

please use woocommerce download product

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digitaldownloadable-product-handling/

check this i hope it is helpfull